# Very basic Connect to mysql / test issue

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I apologize in advance if this is a really dumb question (i'm a newb at php & mysql.

Basically, I am at the step of setting up the connect_to_mysql.php file,
as shown here at (5:50):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaII5QhNCH0

and as shown here:
http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=248

I'm using MAMP.  the ports are 80 / 3306
However I know that at the MAMP start page it says, the following, which also, does not work.:

MySQL

The MySQL Database can be administrated with phpMyAdmin.

To connect to the MySQL Server from your own scripts use the following connection parameters:

Host:   localhost
Port:   3306
User:   root
Password: root

Here is what I have:

this is connect_to_mysql.php:

```
        <?php  
    // Created BY Adam Khoury @ www.flashbuilding.com - 6/19/2008  
/*  
1: "die()" will exit the script and show an error statement if something goes wrong with     the     "connect" or "select" functions. 
2: A "mysql_connect()" error usually means your username/password are wrong  
3: A "mysql_select_db()" error usually means the database does not exist. 
*/ 
// Place db host name. Sometimes "localhost" but  
// sometimes looks like this: >>      ???mysql??.someserver.net 
$db_host = "localhost"; 
// Place the username for the MySQL database here 
$db_username = "builder2";  
// Place the password for the MySQL database here 
$db_pass = "builder2";  
// Place the name for the MySQL database here 
$db_name = "suitstore"; 

// Run the actual connection here  
mysql_connect("$localhost","$builder2","$builder2") or die ("could not connect to     mysql");
mysql_select_db("$suitstore") or die ("no database");              
?>
```

and this is test.php:

```
    <?php   
    // Connect to the file above here   
require "connect_to_mysql.php";  

echo "<h1>Success in database connection! Happy Coding!</h1>";   
// if no success the script would have died before this success message 
?>
```

So, when I load the test site on Chrome, it says:
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving . It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

So, this is probably part of the problem: In DW, when I open test.php it tells me that "this site may have dynamically related files that can only be discovered by the server [ Discover ] [ Preferences ]"

Then, if I click discover, it says:
"Dynamically related files could not be resolved because of an internal server error. [ Retry ]"

Thanks, and sorry if this is a dumb question.  I truly don't know jack about php / mysql.

Comment: find a new tutorial, don't use the  mysql_* functions (see the very large warning in the manual). It is dangerous to use any tutorial\book\video with out considering it's age.

Comment: When debugging, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the beginning of your PHP script.  You are likely encountering a PHP error but your settings are not showing what the error is.

Comment: Remove the indentation before the first <?php in your first php file. Means headers are sent.

Try `require_once("connect_to_mysql.php");`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Use the variable names, not the values, and you can drop the quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure what Alex is referring to.  What are mysql_* functions?

Comment: So, Alex, you would recommend that I use such code as the following...:

// mysql
$c = mysql_connect("example.com", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they should be.

```
mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass) or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("no database");
```